# Proxmox Console to OpenVZ Container has two login shells

Tags: login, openvz, centos7, proxmox

I am using ProxmoxVE. Proxmox is running in Stand Alone Mode. I have a variety of CentOS 7 containers running. When I try to use the "Console" button to login to the machine I am presented with two login prompts, which interfere with each other and prevent me from logging in.

I have tried all three methods of console. NoVNC, VNC, and Spice via remote-viewer.

This is happening on all of my CentOS 7 VMs. I was going to post configs but I am not sure which configs I need to post in order to figure this out.

[image: Example of Issue]

I am able to SSH in, and I am able to vzctl enter 1001 just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue.

I SSH'ed into the container and then from the Proxmox Web Interface started a console and saw that two Gettys were running. I then found out that CentOS 7 starts a getty by default. I disabled that getty and now everything seems to be running fine.

```
systemctl stop getty\@tty1
systemctl disbale getty\@tty1
```

after running those, everything is working properly.